# When building a dictionary for functions, my code automatically executes the function. How can I stop this?

Tags: python, dictionary, python-3.x

Relatively new to python.  Right now I'm having the following problem, I've set a dictionary so that when I give a certain input it executes the defined function, but even when I set the input not to execute the function it still does.  Here's essentially what the code looks like.

```
options = []

def function0(str): print(str,"0")

str = "blahblahblah"

operations = {0:function0(str)}

for i in range(len(options)): operations[options[i]]
```

This code is still printing out the function0 output.  I've also concluded it is executing the function right after I set the dictionary "operations".  Why is that, and how can I get it not to?

Answer (score 5):

The code is executed because you **call** the function: `function0(str)` evaluates to the return value of `function0` with `str` as argument.

If you just want to put the function object in a dict for further use, do

```
operations = {0: function0}
```

---

A couple of side notes:

1. Don't use `str` as a variable name. `str` is a built-in type, and you shouldn't shadow this name with your variables.
2. Looping with an `int` to use it as an index is unpythonic. Also note that you are not calling the functions in your code. Your loop should look like:

   ```
   for op_index in operations:
        operations[op_index](mystr)
   ```

   or:

   ```
   for op in operations.values():
       op(mystr)
   ```

Comment: I don't have str as a variable, name, I was just using that as a filler to try and explain my code, but thank you very much.  That's quite helpful.

Answer (score 2):

This will happen when you type the code in the console, since each line is evaluated immediately.

What you probably intended to do is this:

```
operations = {0:function0}
for i in options:
    operations[i](str)
```

Note that you don't need to have an explicit counter when running through a sequence. So you don't need the `range(len(options))` part.